# SWR not re-rendering when mutate is called

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, swr

I'm trying to create a product list with pagination using SWR and SSR. In order to do this, i'm passing initial data to SWR, and when pagination change, I call a mutate function, bounded to the first SWR request.

The problem is that the page isn't re-rendered, when I print the result of the mutate function, i see that the data has changed but the page just isn't re-rendered and i can't understand why.

**Code** :

```
const ProductList = ({initialData, endpoint, productLimit, productCount}) => {
    const [pageIndex, setPageIndex] = useState(1)
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    console.log(`${endpoint}?_limit=${productLimit}&_start=${pageIndex * productLimit ?? 0}`)
    const {data, mutate} = useSWR(
        `${endpoint}?_limit=${productLimit}&_start=${pageIndex * productLimit ?? 0}`,
        fetcher,
        {initialData: initialData}
    )

    return (
        <div className={cls([styles.product_list_container])}>
            <div>
                <div className={cls([styles.product_list])}>
                    {data.map(product => {
                        return (
                            <ProductCard productData={product}/>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
                <Pagination
                    pageIndex={pageIndex}
                    onclick={async (index) => {
                        setPageIndex(index);
                        setIsLoading(true)
                        mutate().then(resp => {
                            setIsLoading(false)
                        })
                    }}
                    pageNumber={Math.ceil(productCount / (productLimit) - 1)}/>

            </div>
            {isLoading &&
                <LoadingBackdrop/>
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Have you read the [section about pagination](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/pagination) in the swr docs? You shouldn't be using `mutate` for that in the first place. Requesting the page should be a `GET` request. It is not updating any data on the server. Also swr already provides you with a loading state.

Comment: Yes i did, but without the mutate function, I can't even fetch new data so I tried with. Thanks for the advice about the loading state

Comment: Whenever the url provided to `useSWR` changes, it will refetch the data also giving you its loading state. You only have to create the url with start and limit parameters according to the current page state and whenever a user goes to another page you just update the page state. Mutations are only for updating server state (e.g. in a form) which is not what you do here.

Comment: Yeah now I've understand this, but currently I removed the mutate function, I am modifying the URL and I'm updating the state, but SWR isn't fetching new data.

Comment: Did you confirm that no request is being made in the network tab of the debugging tools? Did you confirm that the url changes correctly when updating the page state?

Comment: Yes and yes, I logged the new URL and I see that it is changing but no request is being made in the network tab

Comment: Which version of `swr` are you using?

Comment: SWR Version 0.4.2

Comment: How does `fetcher` look like? Is there any error message in the console?

Comment: The fetcher looks like this : 
`const fetcher = url => axios.get(url).then(res => res.data).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
})`
And there is no error in the console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When providing `initialData` you also need to set `revalidateOnMount: true` in the options or it will always only return the initial data:

```
const {data} = useSWR(
    `${endpoint}?_limit=${productLimit}&_start=${pageIndex * productLimit ?? 0}`,
    fetcher,
    {
        initialData: initialData,
        revalidateOnMount: true,
    },
)
```

[image: Edit eager-darwin-qckch]

Comment: @Oddwerth You're welcome. Mark the question as the accepted answer and/or upvote if you think it solved your problem.

Comment: I can't publicly upvote since I don't have enough reputation ahah

Comment: @Oddwerth That's fine. It will count as soon as you have enough reputation.